# PHP adding characters to jQuery.AJAX posted string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

Couldn't find any answer to this online, or via the search function, so I decided posting it:

I've got a form, like any other, being posted to an AJAX controller within CodeIgniter. The following code is part of a larger form which is being posted.

```
<tr>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef1_active" value="1"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ef1_label" value=""></td>
    <td><select name="ef1_clang" class="input-small">'.$optionlist.'</select></td>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef1_required" value="1"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef2_active" value="1"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ef2_label" value=""></td>
    <td><select name="ef2_clang" class="input-small">'.$optionlist.'</select></td>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef2_required" value="1"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef3_active" value="1"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ef3_label" value=""></td>
    <td><select name="ef3_clang" class="input-small">'.$optionlist.'</select></td>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef3_required" value="1"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef4_active" value="1"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ef4_label" value=""></td>
    <td><select name="ef4_clang" class="input-small">'.$optionlist.'</select></td>
    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ef4_required" value="1"></label></td>
</tr>
```

The form is being serialized, and pushed to the ajax to be saved with this code:

```
var data = {
    content : content,
    property : property,
    data_type : dataType,
    form_id : $('#form_id').val()
};


 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result)
    {

        if(result.html == 'deleted')
        {
           window.location.reload(); 
        }
        else
        {
            $('#newForm').html('');
        }

    }
});
```

The serialized result of the 'content' variable when console.logged:

```
firstname=1&firstname_required=1&prefix=1&lastname=1&lastname_required=1&homePhone=1&homePhone_required=1&emailAddress=1&emailAddress_required=1&ef1_label=&ef1_clang=Code&ef2_label=&ef2_clang=Code&ef3_label=&ef3_clang=Code&ef4_label=&ef4_clang=Code
```

But then when I echo it out in PHP it looks like this:

```
firstname=1&firstname_required=1&prefix=1&lastname=1&lastname_required=1&homePhone=1&homePhone_required=1&emailAddress=1&emailAddress_required=1&ef1;_label=&ef1_clang=Code&ef2;_label=&ef2_clang=Code&ef3;_label=&ef3_clang=Code&ef4;_label=&ef4_clang=Code
```

Notice the `;` added on all the `_label` variables...
Tried renaming the variables, placing it on top of the form etc... Nothing works; PHP keeps adding the `;` on those text fields.

Even stripped the controller down to this:

```
public function save_form_content()
{       
    print_r($_POST['content']); exit;
}
```

Anyone got any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: It's like a small form builder, top part of the form are checkboxes with default form fields like firstname etc. Second part are extra fields that can be assigned to different option fields within our CRM. The markup will then be saved to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in CodeIgniter, it is because you are using either `xss_clean()` or `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`, see the [bug report](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1674). Update CodeIgniter to fix the issue, or look at the Git commit to apply a patch from the commit if can not update entire CI.

According to one of the devs:

> should be fixed replacing regexp on line #797 in the
>   system/core/Security.php by this one :

```
$str = preg_replace('#(^&\#?[0-9a-z]{2,})([\x00-\x20])*;?#i', '\\1;\\2', $str);
```